# RadGrid Binding to a List

Tags: list, binding, inotifypropertychanged, radgrid

XAML RadGrid

```
<telerik:RadGridView d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:A}}" Name="myGridView" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"  Margin="7,7,7,2" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ShowColumnHeaders="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

C# Code

```
Class A:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private List<Fields> MyList;
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public List<Fields> _theList
{
  get
  {
    if (MyList == null)
    {
      MyList = new List<Fields>();
    }
    return MyList;
  }
  set
  {
    if (MyList != value)
    {
      MyList = value;
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_theList"));
    }
  }
}    
}
```

When the items in MyList change dynamically, the radgridview does not update automatically, It works if I reset the Itemssource in the code:

```
mygridview.Itemssource = Null;
mygridview.Itemssource = MyList;
```

I have to reset the itemssource everytime in the code after the MyList changes. Why GridView does not update automatically when contents of MyList change?
Also, During design time it shows me appropriate column headers with no data in the columns because the list is empty. But when I run the application, column headers disappear and no data is displayed in the radgrid when contents of MyList change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

*`When the items in MyList change dynamically,`*

You're notifying when your list property changes...which doesn't cover the above scenario. In order to support what you want, I think you need a collection that supports the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Out of the box, ObservableCollection supports this. It derives from `IList<T>`. So perhaps you could do:

```
 private IList<Fields> MyList;
 private IList<Fields> MyObservableList;
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public IList<Fields> _theList
{
  get
  {
    if (MyObservableList == null)
    {
      MyObservableList = new ObservableCollection<Fields>();
    }
    return MyObservableList;
  }
  set
  {
    if (MyList != value)
    {
      MyList = value;
      MyObservableList = new ObservableCollection<Fields>(MyList );
      // this will throw a null reference exception if no one' is listening. You 
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_theList"));
    }
  }
}
```

If you can forgoe having a `List<T>` instance for having an `ObserableCollection<T>` instance, the above could be even simpler:

```
   private ObservableCollection<Fields> MyList;
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<Fields> _theList
    {
      get
      {
        if (MyList== null)
        {
          MyList= new ObservableCollection<Fields>();
        }
        return MyList;
      }
      set
      {
        if (MyList != value)
        {
          MyList = value;
          // this will throw a null reference exception if no one' is listening. You should make a method OnPropertyChanged that checks if PropertyChanged != null.
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_theList"));
        }
      }
    }
```

Also, as an aside, usually the private members are _camelCase and the public members are PascalCase...not sure if it's intentional.

Comment: Why are we using 2 different lists here (MyObservableList, My List)? can't we just use one list and bind it to radgrids itemssource? Thanks.

Comment: That's what I was saying about making it simpler. I only included that if you can't actually set the property to an ObservableCollection - that is, you could wrap your list with an ObservableCollection (ObservableList). It would be much simpler to just use an ObservableCollection by itself.

Comment: I will try doing it this way! Appreciate it!